# (JAVA)How do I terminate method in certain case in void type method

Tags: java, methods, return

I was struggling with a certain type of coding situation, and I need your advice. For example, if I want to construct a void type method but want to stop at the certain loop without entering the next line, what should I do?

Here is an example.

```
public void insertChild (E parent, E[] child) {
    for (Node<E> node : nodeSet) {
        if (node.getElement().equals(parent)) {
                //I want to stop here if it enters the if-case
            }
        }
    }
    //if not found
    System.out.println("Parent not found");
}
```

The reason I am using void type method is because I want to avoid null pointer exception (since there is nothing to return when an element is not found). Is there any way to make my theory possible? Or should I just use a non-void type method and handle the null-pointer exception?

Comment: return; should do the trick just fine

Comment: oh really? with void type method?

Comment: you are not actually returning something, so yes

Comment: Yes...even with a void type method

Comment: wow thanks! now I can code in peace

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave loop you can use 
break;

```
public void insertChild (E parent, E[] child) {
for (Node<E> node : nodeSet) {
    if (node.getElement().equals(parent)) {
            //I want to stop here if it enters the if-case
          break;
        }
    }
}
```

and if you want leave all method you can use

```
public void insertChild (E parent, E[] child) {
for (Node<E> node : nodeSet) {
    if (node.getElement().equals(parent)) {
            //I want to stop here if it enters the if-case
          return;
         }
    }
}
```

and if it returns the value as example

```
 public int insertChild (E parent, E[] child) {
  for (Node<E> node : nodeSet) {
    if (node.getElement().equals(parent)) {
            //I want to stop here if it enters the if-case
          return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the case where the function just returns (with return;). This would make the answer more complete and is the case that is actually causing the confusion here.

Comment: `System.exit(0)`?? Nope, nope, nope!! Why on earth would you terminate the JVM just to exit a method

Comment: The first method would print the output even when the element is found. The second... I am not sure. I think that will gonna stop all the process if I use System.exit(0). The third method...? I don't think that code will print out in proper situation when I needed.

Comment: @Nico Van Belle that's what I thought haha

Comment: @sbot you can check 3 examples now

Comment: @Nico Van Belle method3 is still weird why would I print out the related statement out of the method

Comment: and there is a trailing close curly bracket at the end of your answer